# Application with two windows

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have WPF app with 2 windows - 
whats the best way to syncronise 2 windows hide/toggle/show ? i.e. if hidden both must be hidden, if restored both must be restored.

thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880710/minimize-child-window-in-wpf-when-owner-window-of-childs-owner-window-minimizes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do they both in the same project and under the same scope?
if so it's simple just bind there `WindowState` together.

on both `onLoad` and `StateChanged` check if the other window already has state and match their WindowState property.

you can see about `StateChanged` in this link:
[Window StateChanging event in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926758/window-statechanging-event-in-wpf)

you can also look at a similar question presented by @cederlof: [Minimize Child Window in WPF When Owner Window Of Child's Owner Window Minimizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880710/minimize-child-window-in-wpf-when-owner-window-of-childs-owner-window-minimizes)